# The smell from eating asparagus

Tags: human-biology, metabolism, food

I am wondering about one thing. I have read different accounts of this (prior to reading it on Wikipedia), so I am wondering.

Here are the two versions I have read:

1. asparagus leads **in a certain percentage of people** to a smell that has to do with a reaction of [asparagusic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagusic_acid). That is: not every human body creates the reactions leading to the "smelly" thiol (sulphuric) compounds.
2. asparagus leads to the processes of the aforementioned asparagusic acid in **everybody** but only a part of the population is able to smell those compounds.

Which one is true? Or is perhaps some other version I haven't heard about.

btw: The Wikipedia article on [asparagus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus#Effects_on_urine) references both versions, too. So I am hoping for a definite answer with references to the respective scientific papers/studies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, both are true.

> ...Individual differences exist in both odorant production and
>   odor perception. The biological basis for the inability to produce the metabolite in detectable quantities is unknown, but the inability to smell the odor is associated with a single nucleotide polymorphism (rs4481887) within a 50-gene cluster of olfactory receptors. *[Pelchet et al. 2010](http://chemse.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2010/09/27/chemse.bjq081.full)*

---

It's an open access paper (yay!), but to cut a long story short:

- Pelchet et al. asked subjects to provide 'before-eating-asparagus'
  and 'after-eating-asparagus' urine.
- The subjects then acted as
  urine-smellers for their own and others samples, and were asked to
  choose between two unlabeled flasks which contained the 'before'
  urine and which contained the 'asparagus' urine.
- Most subjects produced 'asparagus' urine in which an odor was perceived
  significantly more times than expected by chance, and
- Most subjects perceived 'asparagus' urine correctly significantly more times than
  expected by chance, however
- ~8% of subjects were non-producers, and
- ~6% of subjects were non-smellers.
- Finally, looking at the actual amount of successes in perception: for
  Caucasian subjects, one third of the variation in the amount of
  correct odor perception was related to the A allele of rs4481887
  (having AA or AG rather than GG). There was no connection between
  this allele and production.

---

[Pelchat, ML, C Bykowski, FF Duke, and DR Reed. 2010. Excretion and perception of a characteristic odor in urine after asparagus ingestion; A psychophysical and genetic study. *Chemical Senses* doi:10.1093/chemse/bjq081](http://chemse.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2010/09/27/chemse.bjq081.full)

Comment: Best sentence ever in a methods section: "The raw asparagus (125 g) was prepared by combining it with 1 teaspoon of extra virgin olive oil (Colavita brand) and 0.8 g kosher salt and broiling it for 8 min."

Comment: haha.. seems like a cookery manual :D

Comment: @Oreotrephes: guess it's just reproducible this way. Thanks and +1.